# How to store sequence of JsValue into a ArrayBuffer

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following json object what contain a list of json objects. Each of these objects contain informations about a station object.

```
"stations": [
            {
                "cryptName": "Tv_Gara Nord 1",
                "easyName": "Gara de Nord",
                "lat": 45.750287,
                "lng": 21.207498
            },
            {
                "cryptName": "Tv_R Carol 1",
                "easyName": "Regele Carol I",
                "lat": 45.745068,
                "lng": 21.211034
            },
            {
                "cryptName": "Tv_Mocioni 1",
                "easyName": "Piata Mocioni (Sinaia)",
                "lat": 45.746343,
                "lng": 21.21551
            }]
```

I've tried this and I am unable to convert this to a ArrayBuffer with format:

ArrayBuffer(List("cryptName", "easyName", "lat", "lng"), ...)

**[Line 73 .. 77]** The problem is with `(js \\\ "cryptName")(0) ... (js \\\ "lng")(0)`.

How to store correctly all of these stations **not a single one** into my ArrayBuffer?

```
    package backend

    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    import scala.collection.immutable.Seq
    import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
    import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, Props }
    import play.api.libs.json.Json
    import play.extras.geojson.{ LineString, LatLng, FeatureCollection }
    import play.api.Logger
    import actors.GeoJsonBot
    import java.net.URL
    import akka.actor.Actor
    import scala.io.Source
    import akka.cluster.Cluster
    import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate

    object BotManager
    {
        def props(regionManagerClient: ActorRef, data: Seq[URL]): Props = Props(new BotManager(regionManagerClient, data))
        private case object Tick
    }

    /**
     * Loads and starts GeoJSON bots
     */
     class BotManager(regionManagerClient: ActorRef, data: Seq[URL]) extends Actor
    {
        import BotManager._

        var total = 0
    val max = Settings(context.system).TotalNumberOfBots

    import context.dispatcher
    val tickTask = context.system.scheduler.schedule(1.seconds, 3.seconds, self, Tick)
    val port = Cluster(context.system).selfAddress.port.get

    override def postStop(): Unit = tickTask.cancel()

    def receive =
    {
        case Tick if total >= max => tickTask.cancel()
        case Tick =>
            val totalBefore = total
            val originalTrail = total == 0
            println("NODE: " + data)
            data.zipWithIndex.foreach
            {
                case (url, id) =>
                    val json = Json.parse(Source.fromURL(url).mkString)
                    println("URL: " + url + "ID: " + id)
                    Json.fromJson[FeatureCollection[LatLng]](json).fold(
                    {
                        invalid =>
                        Logger.error("Error loading geojson bot: " + invalid)
                    }, valid => valid.features.zipWithIndex.map
                    {
                        feature => feature._1.geometry match
                        {
                            case route: LineString[LatLng] if total < max => total += 1
                            val userId = "bot-" + total + "-" + port + "-" + id + "-" + feature._1.id.getOrElse(feature._2) + "-" + feature._1.properties.flatMap(js => (js \ "name").asOpt[String]).getOrElse("") + feature._1.properties.flatMap(js => (js \ "segment").asOpt[String]).getOrElse("")
                            val stations = feature._1.properties.flatMap(js => (js \ "stations").asOpt[JsValue])

                            import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
                            import play.api.libs.json.JsArray
                            var stationss = feature._1.properties.flatMap(js => (js \ "stations").asOpt[JsValue])
                            val crypt = stationss.flatMap(js => (js \\ "cryptName")(0).asOpt[JsValue])
                            val ename = stationss.flatMap(js => (js \\ "easyName")(0).asOpt[JsValue])
                            val lat   = stationss.flatMap(js => (js \\ "lat")(0).asOpt[JsValue])
                            val lng   = stationss.flatMap(js => (js \\ "lng")(0).asOpt[JsValue])

                            case class Station(cryptName: String, easyName: String, lat: Float, lng: Float)
                            implicit val readsStation = Json.reads[Station]
                            case class Stations(stations: List[Station])
                            implicit val readsStations = Json.reads[Stations]

                            val stations = Json.parse(text).as[Stations].stations.map(s => List(s.cryptName, s.easyName, s.lat, s.lng)).to[ArrayBuffer]

                            println("List: [" + crypt.get + ", " + ename.get + ", " + lat.get + ", " + lng.get + "]")

                            val offset =
                                if (originalTrail) (0.0, 0.0)
                                else (ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextDouble() * 15.0,
                            ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextDouble() * -30.0)
                            context.actorOf(GeoJsonBot.props(route, stations, offset, userId, regionManagerClient))
                            case other =>
                        }
                    })
            }

            println("Started " + (total - totalBefore) + " bots, total " + total)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
case class Station(cryptName: String, easyName: String, lat: Float, lng: Float)
implicit val readsStation = Json.reads[Station]
case class Stations(stations: List[Station])
implicit val readsStations = Json.reads[Stations]
```

(assuming JSON is `{ stations: [ ... ] }`)

Then use the following:

```
val stations = Json.parse(text).as[Stations].stations
    .map(s => List(s.cryptName, s.easyName, s.lat, s.lng)).to[ArrayBuffer])
```

which'll produce the following (given your sample):

```
ArrayBuffer(List(Tv_Gara Nord 1, Gara de Nord, 45.750286, 21.207499), List(Tv_R Carol 1, Regele Carol I, 45.745068, 21.211035), List(Tv_Mocioni 1, Piata Mocioni (Sinaia), 45.74634, 21.21551))
```

Comment: Sems to be right close to my solution but, implicit val readsStation = Json.reads[Station] throws No unapply function found

Comment: @LXSoft The case class and implicit definitions should be as fields, not inside methods.

Comment: Move my case classes and implicits to just above this line beginning "def receive ="

Comment: Json.parse(text) -> My text have Option[JsValue] type how to convert this to string errors over errors. Here is extracted json: feature._1.properties.flatMap(js => (js \ "stations").asOpt[JsValue]), when I printing this have Some(json string)

Comment: feature._1.properties.flatMap(_.asOpt[Stations])

Comment: @LXSoft Brilliant, you're very welcome. Coming from dynamic setups, this was a bit of a headache but once one's got their head around it, it's all plain sailing with strong typing saving our asses here and there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Reads\Writes` macro.

Create case classes, something like,

```
case class Station(cryptName: String, easyName: String, lat: String, long: String)
case class Stations(stations: Seq[Station])
```

Create reads,

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val stationReads = Json.reads[Station]
implicit val stationsReads = Json.reads[Stations]
```

And do conversion,

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)
Json.fromJson[Stations](json) match {
  case JsSuccess(t, _) => ???
  case any: JsError    => ???
}
```

Go through [read/write combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) and [read/write macros](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception)